# I can't use my string in Java code. Where is my fault?

Tags: android

```
 <string name="title_new">Yeni Kamera</string>
```

I have this string in string.xml,

```
public void SetTitle(String _title) {
    title.setText(_title);
}
```

And title is a TextView..

I want to take string for `_title`, how can I do?

Comment: More information needed: Class definition for Title would be good and the exception being thrown would help. Also question marks are cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here. To access a String from your strings.xml file you can call Activiy.getString(int resId). So in your case the code might look something like: `String title = getString(R.strings.title);`. Just make sure you call getString through your activity, it will not work in a generic class.